# What is displacement time graph for this object which is in $xy$ plane going in sine wave like path from A to B. Also can velocity constant in path?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, calculus, speed, displacement

[image]

The path is from A to B in sine wave curve while the displacement is straight line.So how displacement is calculated for graph purpose here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For motion along the given path, the speed (ds/dt) might be constant, but the velocity (as a vector) is constantly changing direction. (The acceleration would be a complex function of position and time.) For each value of (x) the displacement (from a starting point at A) would be a vector going from (A) to the corresponding point on the path. This does not lend itself to being depicted on a graph.